# Adobe Air Jquery loaded html with load() problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, air

I have a index.html file which loads html files.

```
$('#content').load(url,function() {});
```

Inside those html files there is jquery code which works fine on all browsers but when i convert it to adobe air it doesn't work at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: are the external pages loading at all?

Comment: yes they are loading but javascript doesn't work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the livequery plugin saved the day!!! It binds events even after ajax content is loaded!

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery